# Enviar notificações de um site para notificações push android

Tags: php, java, firebase

Eu criei uma rede social, e implementei nela notificações. No entanto, não consigo achar uma forma eficaz de enviar as notificações do site (curtidas, comentários, mensagens) por notificações push para o aplicativo android.
Configurei o firebase, o onesignal, e o aplicativo recebe pushs de testes, mas como enviar essas notificações que estão em meu servidor, para um dispositivo móvel? Sei que preciso do Firebase pra isso, mas como enviar as notificações do servidor para o firebase? Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Estou há meses nesse projeto e não consigo sair do zero.

Answer (score 0):

No seu servidor, basicamente, você precisa fazer um post para essa url (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) com a chave do seu servidor dentro da header `Authorization` e o `Content-Type` (para JSON é "application/json"), passando em formato JSON o token do dispositivo a ser enviada a notificação e um objeto contendo dados para exibir a própria notificação e/ou um outro objeto com dados que você pode querer interceptar no `Service` que você deve ter implementado em Android. Esses parâmetros podem ser, como no exemplo:

```
{
    "to": "token_do_usuario",
    "data": {
        "chave": "algum_dado_que_voce_queira_passar"
    },
    "notification": {
        "title": "Título da notificação",
        "body": "Detalhes da notificação",
        "sound": "default"
    }
}
```

Lembrando que isso é um exemplo. Você pode ter mais detalhes em: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server?hl=pt